# Why Range.value = Range.value not working?

Tags: excel, vba

My dummy data is as follows:

[image]

After filtering the values greater than 20:

[image]

Run this VBA code but the result is different from what I expected:

[image]

I thought the result should be like this:

[image]

If I hide row 13th instead of row 16th, this look pretty bad:

[image]

I tried searching but there's not much info on this, am I missing something?

Comment: At least I confirm this issue - but I can't explain it :-( @BigBen: it is definitley necessary to hide the rows!)

Comment: `Range("D12:D18").FormulaArray = Range("B4:B10").Value` perhaps as a workaround.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, I think it has some problems, if I remove filter B2:B10 now code works normally and if I using formulaarray, replace B9=sum(4,6), then `[B8:B12].formulaarray=[b4:b10].value` doesn't work again. Is there another reliable way that doesn't need to be checked?

Comment: The issue occurs only if the worksheet is filtered. Try without the filter and copy from a range with hidden rows to a range with hidden rows: it will behave as expected.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will do as suggested. <3

Comment: This is definitely a bug.
If anywhere in the sheet is a filter and it is filtered and in the destination range is a hidden row, after the hidden row the first value is repeated. Just hide a row in the destination range. And it is not dependent from where the value comes from.

`Sub BadGuy()

Dim v(1 To 7, 1 To 1), i As Long

For i = 1 To 7

v(i, 1) = i

Range("D12:D18").Value2 = v
Range("D20:D26").Value2 = v

Next

End Sub`

Comment: [How useful is it to say that I tried searching for an answer without saying what search queries I made, and what could be more useful than that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387964/997587)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

'SET THIS IN A MODULE
Public Sub No_Filters(ByRef r As Worksheet)
   With r
      If .FilterMode Then
         .ShowAllData
      End If
   End With
End Sub


'THIS IN SHEET MODULE
Sub test()
   'If a filter is setting ON then can't unhide any hidden lines anywhere, but can hide...
   'So if want to do a SAFE copy, first set filter off. This is excel's default behavior all years
   Call No_Filters(Me)
   Range("D12:D18").Value2 = Range("B4:B10").Value2
End Sub
```